# How to avoid duplicating implemented getter function in PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

While this question is about methods of solving this problem, I am particularly interested in good clean OO design and solutions that conform to current PHP best practices. Thanks in advance for taking a look.

I have the following interface:

```
<?php

interface Tool {

  /**
   * Return the unique name of the tool
   */
  public function getName();

}
```

The majority of classes that implement this interface in my project looks like this:

```
<?php

class Drill implements Tool {

    protected $toolName = 'drill';

    public function getName() {
        return $this->toolName;
    }

}
```

And so **the problem** is I have dozens of classes that repeat this logic, duplicating the $toolName property and getName() logic, breaking the simple rule of 'Don't repeat yourself'

One solution I have considered is the following:

```
<?php

abstract class BaseTool implements Tool {

    public function getName() {
        return $this->toolName;
    }

}
```

Then simply have tool classes extend the abstract BaseTool class:

```
<?php

class Drill extends BaseTool {

    protected $toolName = 'drill';
}
```

However this now means that I lose the ability to force implementing classes to define the function getName() if they extend the BaseTool class, which can lead to incorrect implementations.

I also think that by having the BaseTool class return $this->toolName, it is making assumptions about the implementing classes and breaks encapsulation.

I have used a simple example to demonstrate the problem but hope you get what I'm trying to solve, and that this problem may also relate to more complex situations. Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to avoid duplicating implemented getter function in PHP

Abstract classes are often used to group duplicated code. You're on the right path. As for your doubts about the choice...

> However this now means that I lose the ability to force implementing classes to define the function getName() if they extend the BaseTool class, which can lead to incorrect implementations.

By extending the BaseTool class, a class *inherits* `getName()` (that's the idea with defining it in the abstract class). I'm not sure why that leads to incorrect implementations or why you'd have to "force implementing classes to define it." They get it automatically by extending the abstract class.

> I also think that by having the BaseTool class return $this->toolName, it is making assumptions about the implementing classes and breaks encapsulation.

It might be cleaner if you define the `toolName` in the abstract class, and you set its value in the constructor?

```
<?php

abstract class BaseTool implements Tool {

    protected $toolName;

    public function __construct($toolName)
    {
        $this->toolName = $toolName;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->toolName;
    }

}
```

You define a constructor in the extended class to put its name:

```
<?php

class Drill extends BaseTool {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("drill");
    }

}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I think this adds a lot of clarity. My initial worry was that someone could just extend the abstract class, thereby fulfilling the requirements of the interface, but not actually implement any code to specify the name of the tool. Adding the constructor function goes a step towards addressing this in a way that seems clean and promotes good design. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP 5.4.0+, check out [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)!

You could create a `ToolInterfaceTrait` that just contains the getters / setters for the variable `$toolName`

Comment: This is pretty much the use case traits were made for.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt looks good. Nothing more to say.

> However this now means that I lose the ability to force implementing classes to define the function getName() if they extend the BaseTool class, which can lead to incorrect implementations.

You still force them, they **need** to inherit a class which implements them or implement them on their own.

If it is not feasible that all classes which should implement `Tool` extend from `BaseTool`, feel free to create more base classes which implement `getName()` or implement it directly, like you wish.

Btw, if you plan that all tools should extend `BaseTool`, then the interface isn't necessary at all, at least not for this use case. Interfaces are used for situations where not all classes which are expeted to implement it are inherited from the same base class.

Comment: Some real helpful points there. I suppose I constantly look at interfaces as a way to help enforce aspects of your business logic. Somehow the abstract class seemed to be a way of escaping those constraints. I guess it's not a huge problem if you're writing the code yourself as you will know to implement those required methods. Thanks a lot.